# How do I add global libraries to IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, libraries

I've tried adding .jar files to the `Global Libraries` section in settings, but whenever I create a new project, those libraries still have to be manually added to the project.

I've consulted the documentation on Jetbrains's site (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-project-and-global-libraries.html) and I seem to be doing everything correctly.

With only the `Welcome to IntelliJ IDEA` window open, I've performed the following steps:

1. Open `Default Project Structure` options with CMD+;
2. Select `Global Libraries` from the left pane.
3. Click the `+` in the second pane and select `Java`.
4. Navigate to and select the `jsoup-1.8.2.jar` file which is the library I am attempting to make global and then select `OK`.
5. Click `OK` to close the `Default Project Structure` options window.
6. Select `Create new Project`
7. Select Java from the left panel and then select `Next`.
8. Select `Next` again.
9. Name the project and select `Finish`.

At this point the only `External Libraries` added is `<1.6>`.

So I have to proceed by manually adding the library to the project.

How do I set IntelliJ IDEA to load specific libraries automatically when creating new Projects?

Comment: Show us where you're looking when you want to confirm that the library was added globally.  I've just did a quick smoke test and I can see that the JSoup JAR was added just fine.

Comment: Jetbrains Support got back to me.  It was explained to me that "Global" doesn't mean that it loads with every Java project.  Instead, that you can load multiple libraries into one Global Library, that of which still needs to be  added when creating a new project.  The convenience being that only one Global Library needs to be added instead of each individual library.  Is my understanding of this correct?  Any further explanation to clarify is much apprecited.

Answer (score 0):

Global libs are "global", so it can be used in multiple projects, so the real question is How does IJ know if you want to use this global lib in to "this" project ?

b/c the way "global libs" woks is you could have python virtual-env as global lib, you could have django libs there.. any named-custom set of jars could be a global lib  etc..

so how does ij know-- you need python or django etc in this project? that's why you have to tell/add it manually deciding which one is needed for this project.